# How to replicate numpy.choose() in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to efficiently replicate numpy's `ndarray.choose()` method.

Here's a numpy example of what I'm looking for:

```
b = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
c = np.array([1,0,4])
c.choose(b.T)  # trying to replicate in tensorflow
  -> array([ 1,  5, 14])
```

The best I've been able to do with this is generate a batch_size square matrix (which is huge if batch size is huge) and take the diagonal of it:

```
tf_b = tf.constant(b)
tf_c = tf.constant(c)
sess.run(tf.diag_part(tf.gather(tf.transpose(tf_b), tf_c)))
-> array([ 1,  5, 14])
```

Is there a way to do this that is just linear in the first dimension (instead of squared)?

Comment: Your `numpy` code is equivalent to `b[np.arange(3),c]`. `choose` has a note discouraging the use of a single array (like your `b.T`) for `choices`.

Comment: In `numpy`, the 1-d version of this indexing is `b.flat[np.arange(b.shape[0])*b.shape[1]+c]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, there's an easier way to do this. Flatten your `b` array to 1-d, so it's `[0, 1, 2, ..., 13, 14]`. Take an array of indices that are in the range of the number of 'choices' you are taking (3 in your case). That will be `[0, 1, 2]`. Multiply this range by the second dimension of your original shape, which is the number of options for each choice (5 in your case). That gives you `[0, 5, 10]`. Then add your indices to this to obtain `[1, 5, 14]`. Now you're good to call tf.gather().

Here is some code that I've taken from [here](https://danijar.com/variable-sequence-lengths-in-tensorflow/) that does a similar thing for RNN outputs. Yours will be slightly different, but the idea is the same.

```
index = tf.range(0, batch_size) * max_length + (length - 1)
flat = tf.reshape(output, [-1, out_size])
relevant = tf.gather(flat, index)
return relevant
```

In a big picture, the operation is pretty straightforward. You use the range operation to get the index of the beginning of each row, then add the index of where you are in each row. I think doing it in 1D is easiest,  so that's why we flatten it.